# Conflicting Project name with a Folder name in another project within the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I've created a web application solution `ABC` in VS2013 which contains `project ABC`.

The current structure is as follows:

`ABC` Solution contains the following projects:
`BusinessLogic`
`DataAccess`
`ABC` project

`ABC` project contains the following folders:
`BusinessLogic`
`DataAccess`

I understand that this is a wrong way to design the project, but I have to deal with it as is in the time being. Right now I need to access the classes in the `BusinessLogic` project as well as the `BusinessLogic` folder from my `ABC` project.

I'm using this code to access the `BusinessLogic` folder classes:

```
ABC.BusinessLogic.MyClass MyFolderClass
```

But i'm not sure how i can access the `BusinessLogic` project's classes. The code below also ended up referencing the `BusinessLogic` folder.

```
BusinessLogic.MyClass MyProjectClass
```

How can I access the BusinessLogic project classes from within ABC project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that one way to do it would be to change the namespace's name, meaning. In the ABC solution, in the BusinessLogic project change the namespace to something like `BusinessLogicFirst`, so when you reference this project to the ABC project you'll have access with this code

```
BusinessLogicFirst.MyClass MyprojectClass
```

But for your own convenience change your naming because when someone else will try to maintain your code he'll have problems understanding your way of thinking.

Always code as if the person who ends up maintaining your code is a violent psychopath who knows where you live.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have kept such folder/solution structure, you must have some compelling reason(s) to do so. However here is an 'yes' answer.

By going to you project properties that is directly under your solution `ABC`, change the default assembly name and namespace (under Application tab) to something different and write a post build script (under build events tab) to copy the `<>.dll` to some specific path. And from there onward add a reference to that copied assembly to your project.